# How to capture nested named groups when referencing outer group by name?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

In the list of integer numbers separated by comma, I need to capture (via a PCRE regex) the first occurrence of 12* (if any) and the first occurrence of 45* (if any). How do I do that?
I tried the following but it can only capture inside the first number in the sequence :(

`(?P<number>(?P<n12>12\d)|(?P<n45>45\d)|\d+)(?:,(?P>number))*`

Here's a sample string to test: `11,222,123,444,456,7`. I expect to capture n12=123 and n45=456 here.

**UPD**

As a workaround, my own solution is to declare the delimiter optional (which it isn't), like this:

`(?:,?(?P<number>(?P<n12>12\d)|(?P<n45>45\d)|\d+))*`

- this works for me, but not in all cases (e.g. `,1234`, `123,4`, `1234` and `,123,4` are parsed identically) which i'd like to avoid if possible.

**UPD2**

N.B. C'mon, this is not the real task I'm faced with - it is just a simplified example. Here's another one so that you can get my idea better:

`(?P<animal>(?P<cat>pussy|cat)|(?P<dog>doge|dog)|\w+)(?:,(?P>animal))*`

`pussy,mouse,dog,bird` - has to capture: cat=pussy, dog=dog

Comment: If you don't use the global flag you could look for `\b12\d*` and `\b45\d*` as two differend queries. Is that an option for you?

Comment: Or maybe without named groups: `^.*?\b((12|45)\d*)(?:(?:,\d+)*?,(?!\2)((12|45)\d+))?` and use 1st and 3rd group.

Comment: @anubhava the example above is a simplified as much as possible example of what i'm trying to do. in real example (which i cannot post here b/c nda) subpatterns are more complicated but the same thing persists: i need to capture the single occurrence (if any) of different subpatterns which all are alterations of an item in delimiter-separated list - and this list is only a part of parsed data which consists of several parts

Comment: @JvdV this is just an example. in real case, i'd prefer not to duplicate the code of subpatterns (which you did) and parse them all at a single pass

Comment: Do you have to match both patterns in isingle match only or you are fine with multiple matches also?

Comment: @anubhava there are several such subpatterns and i'd prefer to catch them all in single pass. my workaround allows me to do it, so, so far, i stick with it, but am looking for a better solution if possible

Answer (score 2):

Without named groups, you could capture either 12 or 45 in group 1, and for the second capture group recurse the first subpattern using `(?1)` and before it assert that it is not the same as what is already captured in group 1 using a negative lookahead with a backreference `(?!\1)`

```
^(?:\d+,)*?(12|45)(?:\d*(?:,\d+)*?,(?!\1)((?1)))?
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\d+,)*?` Match as least as possible optional repetitions of 1+ digits and `,`
- `(12|45)\d*` Capture either 12 or 45 in group 1
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `(?:,\d+)*?,` Match as least as possible optional repetitions of `,` and 1+ digits and match `,`
  - `(?!\1)` Negative lookahead, assert not what was captured in group 1
  - `((?1))` Capture group 2, repeat the first subpattern
- `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional to also allow matching 1 capture group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YwkIyJ/1)

---

If you want named capture groups for a single or 2 group values, you can use an alternation with the `J` flag to allow duplicate subpattern names.

The pattern matches either first occurrence of 12 and then 45, or only 12 or only 45.

```
^(?:(?:\d+,)*?(?P<n12>12)\d*(?:,\d+)*?,(?P<n45>45)|(?:\d+,)*?(?P<n45>45)\d*(?:,\d+)*?,(?P<n12>12)|(?:\d+,)*?(?P<n12>12)|(?:\d+,)*?(?P<n45>45))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zQ8XlT/1)

Comment: ++ for `J` flag solution

Comment: can i use the J flag without duplicating the subpatterns? it's not very handy to duplicate all subpatterns, but i need to capture every subpattern once (if it occurs in the subject text)

Comment: pls look at the other example I just attached to the question. seems to me that your suggested solutions don't solve my problem, do they? i need to capture every subpattern, without duplicating them in the regex, but i donno the order in which they appear in the delimiter-separated-list-of-values

Answer (score 1):

Looks like PCRE doesn't allow to capture named subpatterns nested inside a named pattern called by reference. So the exact answer to the asked question is "There's no way. Sorry".

But there's a workaround for this specific case: instead of referencing the subpattern:

`(?P<animal>...)(?:,(?P>animal))*`

- you may avoid referencing it:

`(?:,(?P<animal>...))*`

- but this would require the subject to have a leading delimiter in the beginning, which it doesn't have.

A bad workaround for this is to mark the delimiter as optional:

`(?:,?(?P<animal>...))*`

- but it allows strange sequences to match.

A better solution is to mark the delimiter conditionally required: if the subpattern has already matched at least once, then the delimiter is required, otherwise it must be omitted:

`(?:(?(animal),)(?P<animal>...))*`

i.e

`(?:(?(animal),)(?P<animal>(?P<cat>pussy|cat)|(?P<dog>doge|dog)|\w+))*`

N.B. This will only capture the last match for each subpattern (if any).

Comment: This is a good solution ++. You can update this with `^(?:(?(1),)((?P<cat>pussy|cat)|(?P<dog>doge|dog)|\w+))+$`. However please add that it will only match last match for a named subgroup for eg. `doge,rat,cat,dog`